# PHP MYSQL Multidemensional Array Extract Values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [mobileNumber] => 5555555
        [message] => test
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [mobileNumber] => 555555
        [message] => test
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [mobileNumber] => 555555
        [message] => test
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [mobileNumber] => 5555555
        [message] => test
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [mobileNumber] => 77255552233
        [message] => test
    )

 )
```

loop

```
foreach ($NumbersArray as $number => $message) {
echo "Number: $number Message: $message<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
 }
```

Here is my result:

```
Number: 0 Message: Array

Number: 1 Message: Array

Number: 2 Message: Array

Number: 3 Message: Array

Number: 4 Message: Array
```

What I want is this:

```
 Number: 55555 Message: test
```

Comment: KyleK's answer is the correct solution. [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) is your friend when you're unsure what a variable contains - use it to help your debugging!

Answer (score 5):

Uhhh...Just do

```
 foreach($NumbersArray as $val){
 echo "Number : ".$val['mobileNumber']. " | Message : ".$val['message'];
  }
```

Unless Im misunderstanding your question..??

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($NumbersArray as $number => $message) {
  echo "Number: ".$message['mobileNumber']." Message: ".$message['message']."<br/>";
  echo "<br/>";
 }
```

$message is the second array dimension. so you have to use it as an array. $number is the array key. $Message is the actual array.

the sign `=>` is used if you need the array key in your loop, but since you clearly don't need it you could go a simpler way  which is to just drop the `=>` sign altogether like KyleK's answer.